# in the mouse click method when i call the method get X() and get Y() it return -8 regardless the position

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent, mouselistener, mouse-listeners

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouse click working");
        System.out.println(getX());
        System.out.println(getY());

    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `getX()` and `getY()` on the containing class, *not* on the `MouseEvent`.

e.g. you need

```
e.getX();
```

Comment: i do not want to get tho position of the mouse , its is a board game and i want to get the position of square , the user clicked on it .

Comment: @Michael Samir again to re_read comment by Andrew Thompson about SSCCE, edit your question with code in this form, then after you can want to something, otherwise this question (and with contraproductive comments) isn't answerable ...